# can my application's protocol rely on a graceful disconnect, to detect the end of the stream?

Tags: c#, sockets, networking, tcp

I have an application that sends data over TCP using a Socket (`System.Net.Sockets.Socket`). I indicate that all data has been sent, by doing a graceful disconnect (shutting down sending):

```
Socket.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Send);
Socket.Close();
```

**Question:**

Is it possible that the other side receives a graceful disconnect, without me calling `Socket.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Send)`)? For example by:

- the operating system
- or the socket being disposed
- or me calling `Socket.Close`, without first calling
  `Socket.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Send)`

**Background**

The reason i'm asking is that i suspect a graceful disconnect happened, without me explicitly doing it. If i can't rely on this, then i might have to resort to reserving a special value to indicate the end of the stream, which i would rather not do

Comment: It doesn't matter even if there is operating system magic to somehow close the peer's socket properly, transient network problems can and/or the sender's host crashing can occur, preventing you from getting it a clean disconnect. You program has to be prepared to deal with real-world network issues in a sensible manner.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk i think you misunderstood my question. my program is prepared to not receive a clean disconnect. my program is not prepared for a clean disconnect, that i did not initiate